# Imagen SVG o Imagen PNG

Tags: android

Me gustaría saber si es posible me guíen al respecto de cargar imágenes svg en un elemento `FrameLayout`.

Poseo un elemento `LinearLayout` en donde en su interior se encuentra un `WebView` y un `FrameLayout`, dentro de este `FrameLayout` tengo 3 imágenes que dada las versiones del S.O. deben ser en formato PNG o formato SVG. ¿De qué manera es posible integrar según la versión del S.O una imagen SVG o PNG respectivamente?

Comment: Hola Rodrigo. Sería mejor que coloques la información relevante para reproducir tu problema en la página en lugar de colocar una URL que apunte a tu proyecto y que puede expirar.

Comment: Ok, modificaré mi pregunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si deseas realizar alguna validación por API en tu código puedes realizarlo mediante la clase **[Build](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/os/Build.html)** , este es un ejemplo, suponiendo que el soporte para SVG esta disponible en SO mayores a Android 21 (Lollipop):

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
    //Si es mayor a Lollipop cargar FrameLayout con SVG.
} else {
    //Usa FrameLayout  con PNG.
}
```

Aquí encontraras el listado de las constantes para realizar tu validación:
http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html

Como comentas que tu validación sería mostrar imagenes .png en api <= [11, HoneyComb](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html#HONEYCOMB), este sería un ejemplo:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
    //Si es mayor a Honeycomb (api 11) usa SVG.
} else {
    //Usa PNG.
}
```

Comment: Elenasys muchas gracías.

Comment: Hola, me da curiosidad, si usas SVG Android porque deseas validar?

Comment: Porque esto me está funcionando al menos desde la API 11 hacia arriba y de la 11 hacia abajo debo mostrar imagenes PNG

Answer (score 0):

Puedes realizar dos métodos de carga uno para PNG y otro para SVG, una ves que tienes estos solo verificas la version y dependiendo el dispositivo lanzas los metodos correspondientes.

Codigo para verificar versiones:

```
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.NOMBREDELAVERSION){

             //Si es mayor o igual a la version cargar SVG.

    } else {

             //Dado que es menor cargar PNG.

    }
```

Comment: Max Sandoval, muchas gracias.